# Send accentuated characters inside an email body, how to fix encoding issues

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, smtp

In a script which sends emails through `Net::SMTP`, I've to figure out how to properly encode the email body in order to support accentuated characters. I've separated the email into 3 parts: headers, body and attachment, as from this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_sending_email.htm

Fixing this issue for the `Subject` header field wasn't a big deal:

```rb
require 'base64'

MARKER = 'FOOBAR'

def self.headers
  <<~EOF
    From: someemail@domain.tld
    To: anotheremail@domaim.tld
# Base64 encoded UTF-8
    Subject: =?UTF-8?B?#{Base64.strict_encode64('Accentuated characters supportés')}?=
    Date: #{Time.now.to_s}
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=#{MARKER}
    --#{MARKER}
  EOF
end
```

I was tempted to reproduce the same logic for the email body, without any success. I've try several headers, such as [Language](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-34), [Content-Language](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-49), [Content-Tranfer-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-46), again, without any success. Using Ruby's `.encode!('utf-8')` was also ineffective.

The only working solution I can think of would be to send HTML encoded characters: using `&eacute` instead of `é` inside a HTML block. Though, I'd like to avoid this solution as I've to improve my comprehension of encoding issues.

Does anyone has a suggestion about this issue ?

---

Here's my code so far, if it can help anyone:

```rb
module Reports
  module SMTP
    MARKER = 'FOOBAR'

    def self.send_report(file_path)
      file_content    = File.binread(file_path)
      encoded_content = [file_content].pack('m') # Base64

      mail_content = headers + body + attachment(file_path, encoded_content)

      begin
        Net::SMTP.start('my.smtp.srv', 25, 'HELO_fqdn', 'username', 'p455w0rD', :plain) do |smtp|
          smtp.send_message(mail_content, 'from@domain.tld', ['to1@domain.tld', 'to2@domain.tld'])
        end
      rescue => e
        puts e.inspect, e.backtrace
      end
    end

    def self.headers
      # see above
    end

    def self.body
      <<~EOF
        Content-Type: text/html
        Content-Transfer-Encoding:utf8

        Here's a franglish text with some characters accentués

        --#{MARKER}
      EOF
    end

    def self.attachment(file_path, encoded_content)
      <<~EOF
        Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name = #{file_path}
        Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = #{file_path}

        #{encoded_content}

        --#{MARKER}--
      EOF
    end
  end
end
```

Note: these emails are correctly decoded by ProtonMail webclients, but our company's webclient ([OBM](https://linagora.com/open-source-technologies/obm)) doesn't display accentuated character nor attachment properly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `;charset="utf-8"` to the `Content-Type` header from the body part fixed my problem.

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset="utf-8"
```